# ngConstant:dev returns null

Tags: javascript, gulp, jhipster

I'm almost there with a jhipster generated app that I'm upgrading from v3.0.0 to v4.11, but I've been banging my head against a wall with gulp for almost a whole day now

When running serve/build tasks it seems to have an error when generating the environment from the `ngconstant` task.

If I understand right, gulp will run the task serve or build and then call the `run-sequence`, which should go to the ngconstant task and generate the contents for `app.constants.js`.

Well, it seems to fail when trying to pick up the name of the environment from ngconstant, here's the error:

```
[11:08:29] 'ngconstant:dev' errored after 37 ms
[11:08:29] Error in plugin 'gulp-tslint-log'
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received null
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:1324:5)
    at getFilePath (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:95:27)
    at DestroyableTransform.objectStream [as _transform] (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:60:25)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:352:10)
    at ngConstantPlugin (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:33:16)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/gulpfile.js:162:12)
    at module.exports (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
[11:08:29] Starting 'watch'...
[11:08:29] Finished 'watch' after 147 ms
[11:08:29] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(ngconstant:dev)'
Message:
    TypeError: Path must be a string. Received null
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:1324:5)
    at getFilePath (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:95:27)
    at DestroyableTransform.objectStream [as _transform] (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:60:25)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:352:10)
    at ngConstantPlugin (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:33:16)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/gulpfile.js:162:12)
    at module.exports (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
Stack:
Error: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received null
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:1324:5)
    at getFilePath (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:95:27)
    at DestroyableTransform.objectStream [as _transform] (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:60:25)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:352:10)
    at ngConstantPlugin (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:33:16)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/gulpfile.js:162:12)
    at module.exports (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at pluginError (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:99:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.objectStream [as _transform] (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:65:33)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:352:10)
    at ngConstantPlugin (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:33:16)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/gulpfile.js:162:12)
    at module.exports (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at runNextSet (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:86:16)
    at runSequence (/home/steven/Desktop/Upgraded_MQ/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:97:2)
```

My gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    expect = require('gulp-expect-file'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    ngConstant = require('gulp-ng-constant-fork'),
    eslint = require('gulp-eslint'),
    es = require('event-stream'),
    flatten = require('gulp-flatten'),
    del = require('del'),
    wiredep = require('wiredep').stream,
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    KarmaServer = require('karma').Server,
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    gulpIf = require('gulp-if'),
    inject = require('gulp-inject'),
    angularFilesort = require('gulp-angular-filesort');

var handleErrors = require('./gulp/handleErrors'),
    serve = require('./gulp/serve'),
    util = require('./gulp/utils'),
    build = require('./gulp/build');


var config = require('./gulp/config');

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del([config.dist], { dot: true });
});

gulp.task('copy', function () {
    return es.merge(
        gulp.src(config.app + 'content/**/*.{woff,woff2,svg,ttf,eot,otf}')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'content/fonts/'))
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/fonts/'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(config.revManifest, {
            base: config.dist,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist)),
        gulp.src([config.app + 'robots.txt', config.app + 'favicon.ico', config.app + '.htaccess'], { dot: true })
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
    );
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/images/**')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'content/images'))
        .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5, progressive: true, interlaced: true}))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/images'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(config.revManifest, {
            base: config.dist,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return es.merge(
        gulp.src(config.sassSrc)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(expect(config.sassSrc))
        .pipe(changed(config.cssDir, {extension: '.css'}))
        .pipe(sass({includePaths:config.bower}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.cssDir)),
        gulp.src(config.bower + '**/fonts/**/*.{woff,woff2,svg,ttf,eot,otf}')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.app + 'content/fonts'))
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'content/fonts'))
    );
});


gulp.task('styles', ['sass'], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/css')
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('inject', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js').pipe(angularFilesort()), {relative: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));
});

gulp.task('wiredep', ['wiredep:test', 'wiredep:app']);

gulp.task('wiredep:app', function () {
    var stream = gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(wiredep({
            exclude: [
                /angular-i18n/,  // localizations are loaded dynamically
                'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/' // Exclude Bootstrap js files as we use ui-bootstrap
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));

    return es.merge(stream, gulp.src(config.sassSrc)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(wiredep({
            ignorePath: /\.\.\/webapp\/bower_components\// // remove ../webapp/bower_components/ from paths of injected sass files
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.scss)));
});

gulp.task('wiredep:test', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.test + 'karma.conf.js')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(wiredep({
            exclude: [
                /angular-i18n/,  // localizations are loaded dynamically
                /angular-scenario/,
                'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/' // Exclude Bootstrap js files as we use ui-bootstrap
            ],
            ignorePath: /\.\.\/\.\.\//, // remove ../../ from paths of injected JavaScript files
            devDependencies: true,
            fileTypes: {
                js: {
                    block: /(([\s\t]*)\/\/\s*bower:*(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/\/\s*endbower)/gi,
                    detect: {
                        js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
                    },
                    replace: {
                        js: '\'src/{{filePath}}\','
                    }
                }
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.test));
});

gulp.task('assets:prod', ['images', 'styles', 'html'], build);

gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(templateCache({
            module: 'drugQualityDataManagerApp',
            root: 'app/',
            moduleSystem: 'IIFE'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:dev', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        dest: 'app.constants.js',
        name: 'drugQualityDataManagerApp',
        deps: false,
        noFile: true,
        interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
        wrap:
            '(function () {\n' +
            '    "use strict";\n' +
            '    // DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT THE GULP TASK NGCONSTANT SETTINGS INSTEAD WHICH GENERATES THIS FILE\n' +
            '    {%= __ngModule %}\n' +
            '})();\n',
        constants: {
            ENV: 'dev',
            VERSION: util.parseVersion()
        }
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:prod', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        dest: 'app.constants.js',
        name: 'drugQualityDataManagerApp',
        deps: false,
        noFile: true,
        interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
        wrap:
            '(function () {\n' +
            '    "use strict";\n' +
            '    // DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT THE GULP TASK NGCONSTANT SETTINGS INSTEAD WHICH GENERATES THIS FILE\n' +
            '    {%= __ngModule %}\n' +
            '})();\n',
        constants: {
            ENV: 'prod',
            VERSION: util.parseVersion()
        }
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});

// check app for eslint errors
gulp.task('eslint', function () {
    return gulp.src(['gulpfile.js', config.app + 'app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failOnError());
});

// check app for eslint errors anf fix some of them
gulp.task('eslint:fix', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint({
            fix: true
        }))
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(gulpIf(util.isLintFixed, gulp.dest(config.app + 'app')));
});

gulp.task('test', ['wiredep:test', 'ngconstant:dev'], function (done) {
    new KarmaServer({
        configFile: __dirname + '/' + config.test + 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});


gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['install']);
    gulp.watch(['gulpfile.js', 'pom.xml'], ['ngconstant:dev']);
    gulp.watch(config.sassSrc, ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'content/images/**', ['images']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'app/**/*.js', ['inject']);
    gulp.watch([config.app + '*.html', config.app + 'app/**', config.app + 'i18n/**']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('install', function () {
    runSequence(['wiredep', 'ngconstant:dev'], 'sass', 'inject');
});

gulp.task('serve', function () {
    runSequence('install', serve);
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function (cb) {
    runSequence(['copy', 'wiredep:app', 'ngconstant:prod'], 'inject', 'assets:prod', cb);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

There's not much I have been able to try, I've basically been toying around with the differences between this gulp configuration and the pre-upgrade one, to find not many differences at all, and when changing, finding no positive results.  I've also toyed around with the pom profile for deployment on server, no changes

Comment: which node.js version you are using? as per documentation it should be greater than 6+ or use LTS

Comment: Yeah, running in 6.11.1  However, I started this project in version 4.0.0 and worked fine with basically the same configuration and tasks

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only thing that lets the app build is to remove ngconstant calls from runSequence, leaving `install`, `serve` and `build` tasks like:

```
gulp.task('install', function () {
    runSequence(['wiredep'], 'sass', 'inject');
});

gulp.task('serve', function () {
    runSequence('install', serve);
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function (cb) {
    runSequence(['copy', 'wiredep:app'], 'inject', 'assets:prod', cb);
});
```

Where they used to be like:

```
gulp.task('install', function () {
    runSequence(['wiredep', 'ngconstant:dev'], 'sass', 'inject');
});

gulp.task('serve', function () {
    runSequence('install', serve);
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function (cb) {
    runSequence(['copy', 'wiredep:app', 'ngconstant:prod'], 'inject', 'assets:prod', cb);
});
```

This is far from an ideal workaround, but at least it keeps me on my feet, I would highly appreciate better recommendations for this